# undefined $ and Duration parameter type

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-packages

```
  int score = 0;
  Duration duration = Duration(seconds: Duration.secondsPerDay);

  void callLogs() async {

    Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch()..start();

    Iterable<CallLogEntry> entries = await CallLog.get();
    for (var item in entries) {
      duration = ${stopwatch.elapsed;};
      print('Duration ${stopwatch.elapsed}');
    }
    setState(() { duration > 5 ? score += 1 : score = 0; });
  }
```

When call duration is over 5 second, the int `score` increase by 1. With the code above, I am still getting two errors.

- Undefined name $
- The argument type 'int' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Duration'.

I thought using $ didn't need defining and still confuse with what Duration should be assigned at. Any kind of help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: 1. for () {  ... duration = stopwatch.elapsed; } without ${} 2. duration.inSeconds > 5 in setState callback

Comment: All the error has been gone and I am glad that you helped me. Thanks a lot though I don't know why the 'score' isn't changing as it should by the setState. Would it be because I made a defined something incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s not clear what you’re trying to achieve. As I read the code, you are trying to read a call log from the phone, and if duration is greater than 5 seconds you increment the score by 1, otherwise you reset it to 0? Is that correct?

It may be that your setState is not called from the right place, but it could also be that the duration of stopwatch.elapsed never reach 6 seconds.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear of what I am trying to achieve. When user call someone using 'Flutterdirectcaller' package and the call duration is greater than 5 second, the 'score' gets += 1. call duration less than 5 resets the 'score'(whatever the number it was) to zero. As you said, I tried moving the setState here and there but I see no changes or crashing the app.

Comment: AppBar is where the 'score' is and below it at body, there is a Elevatedbutton. When pressed, it makes a direct call.

Comment: I see, what you want is duration = item.duration; instead of duration = stopwatch.elapsed;

You're taking duration value from stopwatch which is started just before the loop and certainly doesn't take more than a few milliseconds to execute, so your score always stays at 0.

Comment: There are other problems with the code, because the CallLog may have a lot of entries, you may need to sort them if what you want is to get the last call.

Comment: It is harder than what I expected. Thanks though. now I'm getting an error saying A value of type 'int?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'Duration'. Just tried using .toString(); as the document recommended but didn't work.

Comment: items.duration is type int? meaning it can be null. Change the line to:
duration = item.duration ?? 0
it means duration will be zero if item.duration is null.

Comment: Thank you. All the error has been gone but now, nothing happens to the 'score'. call duration less than or greater than 5 second doesn't make any changes to the 'score'. My last guesses are duration variable and CallLog entries. Any suggestion would be helpful. As always, thank you and have a good one

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241953/discussion-between-carry-and-manuh68).